# How to remove unwanted characters in python

Tags: python

I am trying to call an API from the output of a query , the output of the query is int , but when I call the query it returns something like `[(12345,)],` but I want only `12345` how to reconstruct the output

i am using import re regular expression to remove the unwanted characters but it is not working as expected.

```
query = "select some query limit 1"
print (query)
cursor.execute(query)
contact = cursor.fetchall()
print(contact)
id = re.sub(r"[(,)]",r"",contact)
print (111111111111111) #this is just a point to check the output
print(id)
```

Comment: if output is `x`, do `x[0][0]`

Comment: These are no unwanted characters but the indication of a more complex structure, which is reflected by them. Therefore string replacement will not help.

Comment: thanks all it worked!!! i did forget that its a tuple and used it as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[(12345,)]
it is just a tuple inside a list

you can take the element out by using

```
data = contact[0][0]
print(data)
```

will give you the required results

Answer (score 0):

- `fetchall()` returns a list.
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall
- List of rows. Each row is represented by a tuple.

Best way to confirm these kind of 'visual' problems is to find out 'type' of return values.

```
contact = cursor.fetchall()

print( type(contact) )
print(type(contact[0])
```

will give you fair idea about datatypes in them. It will help to parse the data as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The result is an integer in a tuple in a list; you can get the result as a scalar value by unpacking on the left-hand side of the assignment.

```py
[(id,)] = cursor.fetchall()
```